# Three buttons, each start the same Activity with a different Int. But when selecting any button, it loads all 3 Activities

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I'm programming an assignment, and I've got the core functionality operating but I'm quite confused with this. I have 3 buttons on this Activity/Fragment, and each one sends an Intent to a new Activity with a different integer to set the speed of the main game.

Button 1 sets the speed 10, button 2 sets the speed 30, and button 3 sets the speed 50. However, whichever one I click, it starts the Activity with speed 50 first, then when that Activity is finished, it is started with speed 30, and then again after with speed 10. It is essentially cycling and starting all possible Activities, but I only want the selected one starting.

[image: app]

This is the code, as far as I can understand it's somewhere in here.

```
public class LevelsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{    
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_levels, container, false);

    Button b1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button b3 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
            i1.putExtra("s", 10);
            startActivity(i1);
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
            i2.putExtra("s", 30);
            startActivity(i2);
        case R.id.button3:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
            i3.putExtra("s", 50);
            startActivity(i3);
    }       
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put a `break` in your switch statements.

```
switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
            i1.putExtra("s", 10);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
            i2.putExtra("s", 30);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
            i3.putExtra("s", 50);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I can't believe that's how simple it is, rookie error! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This one's a classic, you forgot to put a `break;` between the different cases.

Comment: Wow, my lecturer didn't even know what was up with this; not sure I can have much faith in him any more. Thanks!